# Unable to open export excel file on hiding response headers using URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, httpresponse

I have an *export to excel* code as below:

```
<%
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 600
    
    'Security check passed, proceed:
    Dim conn, rs, sql, x, outlen
    
    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    sql = "exec " & Request.QueryString("sp") & " "
    For t = 1 To Request.QueryString("p").Count
        'Escape single quotes for SQL:
        If t > 1 Then sql = sql & ", "
        sql = sql & "'" & Replace(Request.QueryString("p").Item(t), "'", "''") & "'"
    Next
    conn.CommandTimeout = 600
    conn.Open strConnString_CyberAgent_WithProvider
    rs.Open sql, conn

    'Prepare the response:
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.CacheControl = "Private"  
    Response.Expires = 0 
    Response.Clear
    outlen = 0
    
    'Prepare the message headers (Any subsequent response.writes will fall inside the file!)
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.xls"
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    
    'Output headers:
    For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        If x > 0 Then
            Response.Write(chr(9))
            outlen = outlen + 1
        End If
        Response.Write(rs.Fields.Item(x).Name)
        outlen = outlen + len(rs.Fields.Item(x).Name)
    Next
    Response.Write(chr(13) & chr(10))
    outlen = outlen + 2
    'Loop through records:
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For x = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            If x > 0 Then
                Response.Write(chr(9))
                outlen = outlen + 1
            End If
            Response.Write(rs.Fields.Item(x).Value)
            if not(isnull(rs.Fields.Item(x).Value)) then outlen = outlen + len(rs.Fields.Item(x).Value)
        Next
        Response.Write(chr(13) & chr(10))
        outlen = outlen + 2

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    conn.Close 
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

    Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", outlen

    'Flush the buffer, sending the user the file
    Response.Flush
%>
```

I am able to download the reports normally but in order to mitigate security vulnerability, I hide the response headers like `server name` and `asp.net version` using the **URL Rewrite** in IIS by adding the below in my `web.config`

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Remove Server">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Remove Asp.Net Version">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-ASPNET-VERSION" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" />
        </rule>
            <rule name="Remove Umbraco Version">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-UMBRACO-VERSION" pattern=".+" negate="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>

<customHeaders>
<remove name="Server" />
<remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
<remove name="X-Powered-By" />
</customHeaders>
```

The problem is that adding the rules to block response headers is causing the excel file to not open on download. It throws an error and this makes me wonder if there is any other way to block the response headers while not disturbing the export process.

Comment: Can you show me the error message?

Comment: @samwu It says, cannot open the file. Unsupported excel format. But when I revert back my `web.config` changes it opens fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was able to block all but **Server** response headers and I will share what worked for me so far:

### X-AspNet-Version :

Just add the attribute `enableVersionHeader="false"` to `<httpRuntime/>`. It should look as follows :

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>
```

### X-Powered-By:

1. Open IIS
2. Select the *Sitename* under `Sites` folder
3. Select *HTTP Response Headers* under *IIS*
   [image: response-headers-module]
4. Select `X-Powered-By` and remove the existing value and add an empty string.

[image: X-Powered-By]

Note: I will update once I am able to figure out a way to block server headers as well on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you open Excel files when you disable url rewrite? and if you want to block the response headers without using url rewrite, you can try the following two methods.

1. Using the Registry key.

   Create a dword entry called **DisableServerHeader** in the following Registry key and set the value to 1.

   ```
   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
   ```

   After adding the Registry key, restart the HTTP service using the net stop http command and the net start http command. If the HTTP service doesn’t start up then use the iisreset command. If that also doesn’t work then you can restart the server.
2. Using the URLScan tool.

   Install the URLScan in your machine. Please follow the following link for that:

   https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2013/01/22/microsofts-free-security-tools-urlscan-security-tool/

   After installing URLScan, open the URLScan.ini file typically located in the %WINDIR%\System32\Inetsrv\URLscan folder. After opening it, search for the key RemoveServerHeader . By default it is set to 0, but to remove the Server header, change the value to 1.

Comment: No, the excel file throws error if I implement URL Rewrite module rules in web.config.

Comment: Also, I tried the second method. BUt the URL Scan tool is not available anymore from the Microsoft website it seems. The blog refers to the link on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/working-with-urlscan/urlscan-3-reference  and the download file seem to be missing from the link they mention. I can't download from unknown sources due to security issues. If you are able to find a legit link to download this tool please update the same in your answer. Appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry, Microsoft seems to have removed URLScan tool from the website or you can try the first method.

Comment: Thanks but I will refrain from tinkering with the registry keys since this form of change is not trackable by Version Control systems and if in future there happens a server migration, we will most definitely lose track of this change.